# Change logo in OpenEdx password recovery email

Tags: openedx, edx

As an student when you try to reset your account's password, the received confirmation email from Open edX instance has edX's logo which I want to customize and change it with my own corporation's logo.

I have managed and found the `body.html` here:

```sh
common/templates/student/edx_ace/passwordreset/email/body.htm
```

but it has extended another file `ace_common/edx_ace/common/base_body.html` which I cannot find.

Could you help me please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can find `base_body.html` here:

```sh
./openedx/core/djangoapps/ace_common/templates/ace_common/edx_ace/common/base_body.html
```

But modifying that file wouldn't be a good idea. The better one is to enable comprehensive theming and override it like they do in their example theme (red-theme). To do so check this one:

```sh
./themes/red-theme/lms/templates/ace_common/edx_ace/common/base_body.html
```